# Windows Safe Mode runs simple programs (at least) 3 times faster?

Tags: c++, windows, performance

While doing a lot of benchmarking stuff these days, I stumbled upon something very disturbing / interesting / new to me. After doing some research getting more and more to the point (which i couldnt believe), it seems that windows xp (and probably all other versions as well) runs programs around 3 times as slow as in safe mode.

Take this small program as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    long    i,j,k;

    printf ("Starting...\n");

    k = 12;

    for (i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        for (j = 100000; j > 0; j--)
            k = k * 12;

    printf ("Done... k =%d", k);     // just using k here to prevent the whole block isn't optimized away.

    return 0;
}
```

On my 2.4 Ghz computer it takes ~ 2.5 secs to execute in safe mode, while it takes ~ 8 secs to execute in normal mode. (ThreadPriority = TIMECRITICAL, ProcessClass = REALTIME).
EVEN when i compile and start that code within a vmware-linux session under this very windows normal mode it executes faster (around 5.5 secs).

I also did a lot of cpu cycle measuring and actually the results from safe mode seem much 
more like what you should expect given the amount of instructions processed.

So what did i miss ? Can anybody riddle me this ?

All pointers and hints appreciated,
Thanx.

**SOLVED!** I am sorry guys, this issue is related to my crappy **alienware m15x** which for some reason is throttling down to apparently 1/3 of its cpu power - unless you use evil tools (ThrottleStop.exe) to bring it up to normal speed. Devastatingly sorry for wasting your time. :(

Comment: How are you measuring the time?  There's no measurement code in there.  Also, are you sure the entire loop isn't being optimised away anyway?  The compiler might be able to work out the value of k at compile time anyway.

Comment: Yeah, i left that measuring out for simplicities sake. In fact i also didnt trust anything anymore, so i just made the loop big enough to sit there with a stopwatch in hand. Its really 2.5 secs against 8 - 8.5 secs. and i had a look at the machine code - so no, its not optimized away - also: its the same code run 1 time in normal mode - 1 time in safe mode.

Comment: @Roman Pfneudl, this is interesting, especially since you are not doing anything disk intensive. But have you tried stopping your anti-virus/anti-malware and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I stopped pretty much everything - i also dont have any antivirus / malware thingy running on my pc - also: this behavior is reconstructable on my other pc as well. And still if it were for malware and stuff - no way it could eat 66%. (i really did cpu-cycle measuring with routines down to 100 cycles and also they were stable at ~100 cycles on windows normal while taking ~35 in safe mode)

Comment: Have you tried using [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) in safe and normal mode to see what is really loaded under the hood?

Comment: Yeah, well it says: 90 - 95 % idling at all times (in normal mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly sure that this is something special with your computers.

I ran that code, compiled with MSVC 10 in Release mode, on an old XP netbook and it's a little faster in normal mode than in safe mode for me, not measuring very carefully, but it took about 8 seconds in normal mode and 10 seconds in safe mode.

A bit surprising also that it seems to take as long on your computer in normal mode as on an old single core Atom CPU. You don't mention what computer it is, but I'm assuming that it's supposed to be faster than a netbook so you might have an issue with it.

Comment: You're right - i just figured that my alienware m15x has these problems LOL. sorry.

Answer (score 7):

SOLVED! I am sorry guys, this issue is related to my crappy **alienware m15x** which for some reason is throttling down to apparently 1/3 of its cpu power - unless you use evil tools (ThrottleStop.exe) to bring it up to normal speed. Devastatingly sorry for wasting your time. :(

Comment: excellent. I have been watching this thread, very interested to know what comes out. I am glad it can be explained.

Comment: Yeah, me too. That thing nearly drove me out of my conspiracy-smelling mind. :)

Comment: Thanks for coming back and explaining, even if it wasn't what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

Have you reproduced this on more than one computer? (I presume when you say you tried in VMware/Linux you mean using the same Windows computer as the VMware host, running Linux as a guest inside of it.)

If you've only seen this effect on one computer then you may have a driver slowing things down that isn't being loaded in safe mode.

(Or some other piece of software, but probably a driver from what you've said about the CPU appearing to be idle and the code not interacting much with the OS, unless something is delaying the actual printf output, which is possible.)

e.g. Some driver might be holding low-level locks that prevent proper task switching, or something might be using a resource which delays the printf call. Neither would necessarily be visible in terms of CPU usage.

Comment: I totally put the printf out of the equation for this is another complex io locking/unlocking function, and tested it with several functions doing just computational stuff, measuring blocks down to just 4 assembler instructions only. Ok, i think i have to put a better example up here to better showcase what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

- You say you measured the time using a stop watch, that's not going to give you the real time spent on your process, you need to profile the code properly
- Have you tried any other programs?
- Give this test a shot, two XP VM's, one VM starts in Safe Mode and one in normal mode, start the program in both VM's around the same time and measure the cpu time each one takes (not the clock time)

Comment: i used rdtsc to measure the cpu cycles. I set the ProcessAffinity to just use 1 processor, because i know rdtsc can sometimes act funny when not doing so. i measured small portions of simple code resulting in this 33% / 100 % behavior. I even measured a simple sleep (2000), which in both cases resulted in ~1952 ms. So, that proved that the rdtsc was at least somehow working correctly -> it just kept delivering this insane discrepancy. Starting complex programs won't help i fear. I won't get any useful information out of that.

Comment: I didn't say starting a complex program, just a different one. It will tell you if it is something specific with this application or more general. You also need to do proper profiling to know where the time is spent

Answer (score 2):

Does DEP run under Safe Mode? I'm wondering if it's some form of security/sandboxing or something similar. Interest trend though.

Comment: No, not likely - its turned on for windows processes only (at least on my machine).

Answer (score 2):

Like Leo Davidson said, it's probably caused by a driver that is not loaded in safe mode.

1) It could be a hardware driver : do both computers have the same hardware configuration?

2) Or even malware (with rootkit!): this means that the malicious driver will hide itself in normal mode, so you could compare the listings of files in sytem32\drivers\ with their sizes/MD5s took in both, safe and normal modes. You can use http://www.virustotal.com/ to scan any file.

Comment: Well no, it shouldnt slow down the program by more or less exactly 66 %. Drivers and Malware are also just processes that get their amount of cpu-cycles at times. This should lead to unstable results at most.

Comment: Drivers aren't processes; they run inside of every process and can change things quite drastically. Another point, unrelated to drivers, is to make sure you're looking at processes for all users when checking resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because in safe mode there are far less processes running in the background, hence less stress on the CPU & memory usage.

Comment: No, thats definitly not the point i guess. Windows cant eat 2 3rds of the whole processing power on a stable rate.

Comment: But why small programs take more time?

Comment: Its not really the small programs - i just took a very small program as an example to make it easily reconstructable - my crazy hunch is that windows puts the processor in some sort of "overly debugging" mode to be able to catch more exceptions or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If your using C++ you could use QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter to accurately time a piece of code for example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

LARGE_INTEGER startTimer, endTimer, frequency;//declare some big numbers to use in timers
double timeTakenInSeconds;

int main()
{
    //start timer: 
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);//retrieves the frequency of the high-resolution performance counter(if exsists on this hardware)
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTimer);//retrieves the current value of the high-resolution performance counter(in counts)

    //do something that you want to time here eg call a sorting method


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTimer);//endtimer
    timeTakenInSeconds = (endTimer.QuadPart-startTimer.QuadPart) / (double)frequency.QuadPart;//Work out time difference
    cout <<"somthing took:  \t" << timeTakenInSeconds << " seconds" <<endl;//print the time takken

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP knows how to time a piece of code, he's interested why it's slower in normal mode than in safe mode.